# Azure Automation Analysis Services Processing

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-analysis-services, azure-authentication

I come across an unexpected error, when trying to process a table in Azure Analysis Services using Azure Automation. I have followed a tutorial suggesting using PowerShell Gallery module - SQLServer with `Invoke-ProcessTable`. My final code in the Azure Automation looks like this:

```
$AzureCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "ks"
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $AzureCred | Out-Null
Invoke-ProcessTable -Credential $AzureCred -DatabaseName DBNAME -RefreshType 
"Full" -Server SERVERNAME -TableName TABLENAME
```

Unfortunatelly, I always end up with:

```
Invoke-ProcessTable : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
At line:25 char:1
+ Invoke-ProcessTable -Credential $AzureCred -DatabaseName DBNAME -R ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-ProcessTable], TargetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ProcessTable
```

Additionally, I have tested `Invoke-ProcessTable` code locally and it works perfectly. Credentials used are of a person with both admin access to Analysis Services and the subscription we are using.

I would appreciate any suggestions.